Long running Isolate does not cause ANR in flutter
I want to verify that long running Isolates would cause ANR(App not responding) in Flutter. For that I bootstrapped flutter code and created a button which when pressed would execute a very long running operation(on different isolate) that I am expecting it would block Main Isolate causing App to be unresponsive.
I saw that Future.delayed uses Timer internally so both Timer and Future are running on different isolate but the app is still fully responsive.
Expected Behavior: Long running Isolates launched on button tap should stop Main Isolate(which is updating UI) execution.
Observed Behavior: UI is fuly repsonsive even though there are other long running isolates.
Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Text(
          'You have pushed the button this many times:',
        ),
        Text(
          '$_counter',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text("Press me to Trigger ANR"),
          onPressed: () {
            Timer(const Duration(seconds: 10), () {
              debugPrint('Now 10 seconds ANR is over.');
            }); //---------------------> This is not causing ANR
            //Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 30), () {
            //  debugPrint('Now 30 seconds ANR is over.');
            //}); ---------------------> This also does not cause ANR
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),


The code that you posted will run in the main isolate. To run a calculation in a separate isolate you will have to use Isolate.run() or spawn a new isolate. See https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/isolates

Okay Now I got it. onPressed() does not launches another Isolate but simply pushes an event to the Event Queue of the current isolate. I misunderstood this. Thanks. The callback to timer and future are running only after specified duration has elapsed in the same isolate. But why waiting for that timer to finish is not causing main(UI) isolate to pause ? Like counting 10 or 30 seconds is also an event needed to be executed on the same event loop

To trigger an App Not Responding (ANR) error in Flutter, you need to block the main isolate's event loop. Using Timer or Future.delayed won't cause an ANR because they run asynchronously and do not block the main isolate.
Here's how you can simulate a long-running operation on the main isolate that would block it and cause an ANR:

Long-running computation on the main isolate: This will block the
main thread and make the UI unresponsive.
Long-running operation in a separate isolate: Although isolates run
in parallel to the main isolate and should not block the UI, ensure
that your method of communication between the isolates does not
inadvertently cause blocking on the main isolate.

